# Alkylation of enolates using tertiary halide

Tags: synthesis

I was recently studying the alpha alkylation of enolates using LDA followed by subsequent treatment with primary halides to give the product.I was wondering what happens with teritary halides. My guess is that elimination will take place,and the carbon nucleophile formed by LDA will abstract a proton fron the tertiary halide giving an alkene. Is this chain of reasoning correct?

Comment: Sounds good to me!

Comment: Also to me. These kinds of alkylation are better done by Lewis acid mediated reaction of the silyl enol ether with the tertiary halide.

Comment: @https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/55119/user55119 Thanks a lot for your responses people. What happens with secondary halides?